# Unable to Clone CloudGoat from RhinoSecurityLabs

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-security

I am trying to install the [Rhino Security Labs CloudGoat](https://github.com/RhinoSecurityLabs/cloudgoat) on my AWS Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Free-tier EC2 instance. I followed the directions for [setting up an admin user and configuring the AWS CLI](https://rhinosecuritylabs.com/aws/introducing-cloudgoat-2/) and also [set up terraform v0.12](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/install.html) per the directions in the linked sites and the [directions on GitHub](https://github.com/RhinoSecurityLabs/cloudgoat). I also configured my instance's security group to allow All traffic.

However, when I run the git clone command I get "Permission denied" error. See below for full output:

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:RhinoSecurityLabs/cloudgoat.git ./CloudGoat
Cloning into './CloudGoat'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (<ipv4>)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:<RSA key fingerprint>.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,<ipv4>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Do I need to associate an SSH key on GitHub to my account and if so how do I do that? I'm not sure what else to try at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have SSH Keys on EC2 that can authenticate your requests to Github. I encountered the same error when I was installing Cloudgoat on my personal machine (not EC2), and it worked when I setup my SSH keys ([generate](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) and [add it to my git profile](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)).

You will probably need to do the same with EC2 - [Generate a key pair on EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair) and add the public key to your git profile.